# How to add attribute advance properties in magento 2.2.7

Tags: product-attribute, custom-attributes, magento2.2.7

How to add attribute for product attribute advance properties in magento 2.2.7

I want to implement yes/no attribute for product and second attribute for image attribute for **Product Attribute**